# sendmail displaying issues

Tags: sendmail

I'm having a issue with `sendmail`. I'm sending `echo` multiple text with `sendmail` (1 liner) but it isn't breaking up the line.

my code is like this:

```
$ echo "$text1\n$text2\n$text3\n$text4 | mail -s "subject" myemail
```

But somehow it just doesn't break the line, any tips?

Comment: Use `echo -e "$text1\n$text2\n$text3\n$text4" | mail -s "subject" myemail`

Comment: echo -e didnt work, in my mail as output it showed "-e" before my text.

Comment: You must have put `-e` inside quotes… I using it a lot. Works for 100%!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $ printf "$text1\n$text2\n$text3\n$text4" | mail -s "subject" myemail
```

**NOTE:** (assuming no `%` in `$text`)

You can also do it like this too:

```
$ (echo $text1 ;echo $text2 ;echo $text3 ;echo $text4 ) | \
    mail -s "subject" myemail
```

This last one creates a sub-shell with the parens wrapping the output of all the `echo`'s. That output is then piped to the `mail` command.

Comment: arche, you are a hero, it worked. you helped me so often. thanks man.